# Слайдер пунктов списка на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

Прошу помочь написать скрипт прокрутки списка пунктов на чистом JS.
Суть проблемы такова: 
Есть сайдбар с двумя дивами, где каждый имеет свой список. Первый `div` следует оставить как есть, а второму дать возможность прокрутки по нажатию на кнопку вверх/вниз. 
На что хватило знаний:

```js
var warrd = document.body.querySelector(".mini-arrow-down-btn"); //стрелка вниз
var warru = document.body.querySelector(".mini-arrow-up-btn"); //стрелка вверх
window.onload = function() { //добавляю классы
  var wbody = document.body.querySelector(".visas-module-menu-body").lastChild;
  wbody.classList.add("w-viewport");
  var wlist = document.body.querySelector(".w-viewport > ul");
  wlist.classList.add("w-list");
};
warru.onclick = function() {
  wlist.scrollTop += 100;
}
warrd.onclick = function() {
  wlist.scrollTop -= 100;
}
```

```css
.w-viewport {
  width: 180px;
  height: 317px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.w-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<?php foreach ($list as $group_name => $group) : ?>
<div class="visas-module-menu-items">
  <ul>
    <?php $gn=Визы; if (!($group_name == $gn)) { ?>
    <div class="visas-module-items-category text-center">
      <?php echo JText::_($group_name); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php foreach ($group as $item) : ?>
    <li class="visa-module-btn">
      <span class="visa-module-btn-bg"></span>
      <div>
        <div class="country-flag-mini" style="background-image: url('/images/country_flags/<?php echo $item->alias; ?>.png');"></div>
        <span class="visa-module-btn-title"><?php echo $item->title; ?></span>
      </div>
      <input value="<?php echo $item->alias; ?>" style="display: none;">
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php foreach ($group as $item) : ?>
<div class="visas-module-item visas-module-item-<?php echo $item->alias; ?>">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 block-anim">
    <h2 class="visas-module-item-title">
      <?php echo $item->title; ?>
    </h2>
    <p class="visas-module-item-introtext">
      <?php echo $item->displayIntrotext; ?>
    </p>
    <div class="visas-module-item-readmore">
      <a class="visas-link" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">читать далее</a>
      <button class="red-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-SYA"><span><span>оформить визу</span><span>оформить визу</span></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php $image = json_decode($item->images, true); if($image) : ?>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs block-anim">
    <div class="visas-module-item-img" style="background-image: url('/<?php echo $image['image_intro'] ?>');">
      <span class="white-bg"></span>
      <div class="icon big-eye-btn"></div>
      <div class="openimg-btn"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

На выходе будет вот такой сайд бар:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дайте направление куда копать. Спасибо.

Comment: какой не будь вертикальный слайдер применить можно

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский есть примеры? Не очень шарю)